# How to track webservices calls

Tags: java, web-services

I am using a webservice that is hosted on an independent server with Oracle DB connection. The webservice is called from presentation side and from a CMS we use. Since this service doesn't return any success or error message back to the client, I was hoping for a way to track all calls made and action taken on this service. Is there a way I track all calls made to this Service. I am using Java platform

Comment: It might be helpful to add more information about which type of web service you are calling and how exactly you are doing that - which protocol, which kind of client you are using, ...

Comment: I am using web services provided by Tridion like ugc_webservice.jar. I need to track in detail all activities performed using these services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several different ways to approach this:

1. If you have access to the web service code, it's trivial to add a simple JDBC call to send an update to a table that holds a counter in the Oracle DB.
2. You can implement something on the client side that stores it in a full database, SQLite or even in memory and periodically writes the content in memory to a flat file.
3. Depending on how things are configured, you can write a log analyzer that sifts through the server log for calls to that service.

   1. This is easy to implement with log4j. Just look up how to add a log4j configuration to your project via a few Google searches and you can customize the message to something really convenient for you to write a quick script to read.

Comment: Hi Mike, I am not sure about 1. Regarding 2, client side would be able to track web service calls. But I would not be able to track response returned back from a service. 3. Log analyzer, what if I have to reduce the log level to improve performance. I won't be able to capture anything useful from the logs